# Is there a standard for threshold (m out of n) cryptosystems?

Tags: cryptography

I'd like to use a m out of n cryptosystem for storing sensitive data (2 out of 3 to be exact). I've learned from Wikipedia that it's called a [threshold cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem), but I haven't found any practical implementations.

For regular public key cryptography we have standards like PEM and implementations like OpenSSL ready to use. Is there something similar for m out of n cryptography? I would like to avoid having to invent my own ways to store (serialize) keys and encrypt them with a password. All of this is trivial to use with OpenSSL. And the worst thing would be relying on some homebrew implementation of a crypto algorithm.

I'm most interested in Python libraries, but I'd like to hear if there is a standard and an implementation in any language.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's a homebrew implementation, but I think it's pretty good.  And it's in Python.  Take a look at http://programmingpraxis.com/2011/06/17/adi-shamirs-threshold-scheme/.

Comment: It's just pure algorithm, so not what I'm looking for, but a nice implementation in case there is no standard. Thanks!

Comment: I found implementation of this algo as practical executable called `ssss`
http://point-at-infinity.org/ssss/

You can install it via apt-get or homebrew for example.