# split private key(k1) such that only any two keys are necessary to decrypt it?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, openssl, crypt

I encrypt data using public key(k1). I decrypt it using private key pk1
Is it possible to split private key(pk1) into keys pk2, pk3, pk4 and pk5 in such a way that only any two keys are necessary to decrypt it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [threshold cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_cryptosystem). There is [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6558248/is-there-a-standard-for-threshold-m-out-of-n-cryptosystems) about the topic.

Unfortunately, it seems that there is no widely implemented public algorithm available.

Comment: Yes. I found exactly what I was looking for: Shamir's Secure Secret Sharing Algorithm. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing